# ExceptionFilter difference between OnExceptionAsync vs.OnException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

That's it.

When writing **custome exception filter** in MVC or WebApi, what is the difference between **OnExceptionAsync** and **OnException** methods?
Is it so that OnExceptionAsync is called only when using asynchronous controllers?
Or both are called?

When to use which?

How to use OnExceptionAsync which returns task result?

Some base code to ilustrate:

```
public class ApiExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        //TODO exception handling
    }

    public override Task OnExceptionAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //TODO exception handling
    }
}
```

Comment: yes OnExceptionAsync filters are for newest async controller coming in mvc 5

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think OnExceptionAsync is used with async Actions.

If you want a simple scenario like sending a serializable description of the error, you can override OnException and not OnExceptionAsync, since OnExceptionAsync invokes OnException in the [ExceptionFilterAttribute default implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Filters/ExceptionFilterAttribute.cs#L17):

```
public override void OnException(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    actionExecutedContext.Response = actionExecutedContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new 
    {
        Message = "An unexpected error has occured",
        Description = actionExecutedContext.Exception.Message
    });

    actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.CacheControl = new System.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
    {
        NoCache = true,
        NoStore = true
    };
}
```

But you may want to log the exception in a database and take advantage of the async behavior :

```
public override async Task OnExceptionAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await LogException(actionExecutedContext.Exception);
}
```

The async and await keywords will do the job for you to manage the async behavior. You don't need to return the Task object.

Comment: Thanks for giving some light on the OnExceptionAsync method, seems you are right.